# How to reinstall apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management

My package manager has been corrupted. How do I re-install it from scrach without manually downloading all the dependencies?

Comment: Use one of the methods in http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline, then `dpkg -i` the whole thing.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using 14.10 version.

Answer (score 0):

You can download `apt` from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/apt) and install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i package_name
```

The major difference to `apt-get` is of course, that you don't use `apt-get`: use just `apt`.

[This](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-get.html) give you a bit of information on `apt`.

Comment: Are you sure that the op should download the trusty version, vs the wily or vivid versions?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I suppose that he's using 14.04+ and the link covers that

Comment: I get dpkg: `dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 apt depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.6); however:
  Package libstdc++6:amd64 is not configured yet.`